# Python 'forgetting' a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

So, i am trying to write variables into a separate .txt file, and python says my variable is not defined, even though it uses the same variable previously in the   program

There is where i assign and use the variable operator_choice:

```
    operator_choice = input ("Ok Mate, now chose your function: multiplication, division, addition or subtraction!")        
    if operator_choice in times:
        while Question < 12:
            Mathmultiplication();
        break
    if operator_choice in division:
        while Question < 12:            
            Mathdivision();
        break
    if operator_choice in subtraction:
        while Question < 12:
            Mathsub();
        break
    if operator_choice in addition:
        while Question < 12:
            Mathadd();
        break  
    elif operator_choice not in total_difficulty:
        print ("\nNot an option, try again")
```

but when i try to write it to a .txt file here:

```
Results.write (", " + operator_choice)
```

it gives me this error:

```
NameError: name 'operator_choice' is not defined
```

Can someone please tell what is happening, why and how to fix it?
This is not in a function, it is, however in a while loop

full code is a s folows:

```
import random
#just some variables
times = {'*'}
divide = {'/'}
other = {'-','+'}
myName = input ("So user, whats your name?... ")
#Operator stuff
correct = 0
incorrect = 0     
Question = 0
#Defining The Math
def math():
    global Question
    global correct
    global incorrect
    Question = Question + 1
    print ("________________________________________________________________________________")
    print ("Ok Then, This is question:", Question)
    print (str(number) + operator_choice + str(second_number) , "= ?")
    answer = eval(str(number) + operator_choice + str(second_number))
    guess = input ()
    if guess == str (answer):
        print('Correct!')
        correct = correct + 1
    elif guess != str(answer):
        print("Sorry, but that's wrong!The answer was:", answer, "Onto the next question then!")
        incorrect = incorrect +1    
def division():
    global Question
    global correct
    global incorrect
    Question = Question + 1
    print ("________________________________________________________________________________")
    print ("Ok Then, This is question:", Question,)
    number = (random.randint (12,24) * level)
    second_number = (random.randint(2,12)* level)
    print (number,"/",second_number)
    answer = number//second_number
    guess = input ()
    if guess == str (answer):
        print('Correct!')
        correct = correct + 1
    elif guess != str(answer):
        print("Sorry, but that's wrong!The answer was:", answer, "Onto the next question then!")
        incorrect = incorrect +1
#Difficulty
four = {'Impossible','impossible','4'}
total_difficulty = {'1','2','3','4'}
while True:
    print ("Ok,; Choose a difficulty: 1 , 2, 3 or 4(Changing operators, Near impossible!)...")
    difficulty_choice = input ()
    if difficulty_choice not in total_difficulty:
        print ("Not an option, try again")
    else: break
level = int(difficulty_choice)
if difficulty_choice not in four:
    print ("________________________________________________________________________________")
    while True:
        operator_choice = input ("Ok Mate, now chose your function: \nmultiplication (input * )\ndivision (input / ) \naddition (input + ) \nsubtraction (input - )\n...")        
        if operator_choice in times:
            while Question < 12:
                number = (random.randint (2,6) * level)
                second_number = (random.randint (2,6) * level)
                math();
            break
        if operator_choice in divide:
            while Question < 12:            
                division();
            break
        if operator_choice in other:
            while Question < 12:
                number = (random.randint (1,25) * level)
                second_number = (random.randint (1,25) * level)
                math();
            break  
        elif operator_choice not in total_difficulty:
            print ("\nNot an option, try again")
#Randomised operators
elif difficulty_choice in four:
    print ("you have chosen: Random. Be warned, These questions are HARD, and the operator WILL change!")
    Question = 0
    while Question < 12:
        Question = Question + 1
        print ("________________________________________________________________________________")
        print ("Ok Then, This is question:", Question)
        ops = ['*', '/', '+', '-']
        op = random.choice (ops)
        number = random.randint (2,25)
        number2 = random.randint (2,25)
        number3 = eval(str(number) + op + str(number2))
        number3 = int(number3)
        answer = eval(str(number3) + op + str(number))
        answer = int (answer)
        print (number3, op, number)
        guess = input()
        if guess == str (answer):
            print('Correct!')
            correct = correct + 1
       elif guess != str(answer):
            print("Sorry, but that's wrong!The answer was:", answer, "Onto the next question then!")
            incorrect = incorrect +1
#Outros
print ("________________________________________________________________________________")     
print ("Game Over!", myName," got:", correct,"questions right, and",incorrect,"Wrong!")
if correct == 12:
print ("Congratz",myName,"! You got a perfect score! See ya around",myName,"!")
else: print ("good luck next time! Bye!")
#save results
correct = str(correct)
incorrect = str(incorrect)
Results = open (r"Results.txt", 'a')
Results.write ("\nHello There Teacher! " + myName + " got: " + correct + "correct, and: " + incorrect + " wrong on level: " + difficulty_choice + ", ")
Results.write (operator_choice)
Results.close()
```

Comment: Is the `Results.write` in the same function as the above code?

Comment: Yeps, please post a full working reproducible exampel: [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: , so the full code has been put up. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Until you post your full code, you cannot expect to get a full answer. However, I can give you a possible (and likely) solution:

Your code that you have posted above is in a separate function, thus, the scope of `operator_choice` is only defined within that function. Make sure you return the variable in your function, or call `Results.write` in that function.

Example:

```
>>> def foo(): 
...    bar = 1 
...
>>> bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
>>> foo()
>>> bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```